# Java calculator nearly complete

Tags: java, calculator

I need some help making the calculator buttons be able to enter multi digit numbers.
Thanks. It is nearly complete and it is for a school project. I have been unable to find the answer to the problem. If anyone knows what i could add to allow multidigit numbers into the text field using the buttons it would be much appreciated.

```
 //These are the imports that are used in the code 

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Container;

public class calculatorfinal implements ActionListener{

    JFrame guiFrame;
    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JTextField tf1;

    int calcOperation = 0;
    int currentCalc;
    int p = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

         //Use the event dispatch thread for Swing components
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
         {

            @Override
             public void run()
             {

                 new calculatorfinal();         
             }
         });

    }

    public calculatorfinal()
    {
        guiFrame = new JFrame();

        //This exits the program when the frame closes
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("calculator");
        guiFrame.setSize(300,350);

        //This will centre the JFrame in the middle of the screen
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //This sets up tf1 (text field 1), it allows it to be editable aligns the text to the     right
        tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        tf1.setEditable(true);

        guiFrame.add(tf1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        //Grid that has five rows and three columns
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,3));   
        guiFrame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Adding the number buttons

        for (int i=1;i<10;i++)


        {
       addButton(buttonPanel, String.valueOf(tf1.getText()+i));
        }


        {
            addButton(buttonPanel, String.valueOf(tf1.getText()+p));


        }

        JButton buttonDecimal = new JButton(".");
        buttonDecimal.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonDecimal);

        JButton buttonPlus = new JButton("+");
        buttonPlus.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20));
        buttonPlus.setActionCommand("+");

        OperatorAction subAction = new OperatorAction(1);
        buttonPlus.addActionListener(subAction);

        JButton buttonMinus = new JButton("-");
        buttonMinus.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20));
        buttonMinus.setActionCommand("-");

        OperatorAction addAction = new OperatorAction(2);
        buttonMinus.addActionListener(addAction);

        JButton buttonTimes = new JButton("*");
        buttonTimes.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20));
        buttonTimes.setActionCommand("*");

        OperatorAction multiplyAction = new OperatorAction(3);
        buttonTimes.addActionListener(multiplyAction);

        JButton buttonDivide = new JButton("/");
        buttonDivide.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20));
        buttonDivide.setActionCommand("/");

        OperatorAction ActionDivide = new OperatorAction(4);
        buttonDivide.addActionListener(ActionDivide);

        JButton buttonClear = new JButton("Clear");
        buttonClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                tf1.setText("");
                //textfield.setText(null);
            }
        });

        JButton buttonEquals = new JButton("=");
        buttonEquals.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20));
        buttonEquals.setActionCommand("=");
        buttonEquals.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                if (!tf1.getText().isEmpty())
                {
                    double number = Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText()); 
                    if (calcOperation == 1)
                    {
                        double calculate = currentCalc  + number;
                        tf1.setText(Double.toString(calculate));
                    }
                    else if (calcOperation == 2)
                    {
                        double calculate = currentCalc  - number;
                        tf1.setText(Double.toString(calculate));
                    }
                    else if (calcOperation == 3)

                    {
                double calculate = currentCalc  * number;
                tf1.setText(Double.toString(calculate));
                }
    else if (calcOperation == 4)

                    {
                double calculate = currentCalc  / number;
                tf1.setText(Double.toString(calculate));
                }
}}});

        buttonPanel.add(buttonPlus);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonMinus);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonEquals);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonTimes);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonDivide);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonClear);

        guiFrame.setVisible(true);  
    }

    //All the buttons are following the same pattern
    //so create them all in one place.
    private void addButton(Container parent, String name)
    {
        JButton but = new JButton(name);
        but.setActionCommand(name);
        but.addActionListener(this);
        parent.add(but);
    }

    //As all the buttons are doing the same thing it's
    //easier to make the class implement the ActionListener
    //interface and control the button clicks from one place
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        //get the Action Command text from the button
        String action = event.getActionCommand();

        //set the text using the Action Command text
        tf1.setText(action);       
    }

    private class OperatorAction implements ActionListener
    {
        private int operator;

        public OperatorAction(int operation)
        {
           operator = operation;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            currentCalc = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText()); 
            calcOperation = operator;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is extremely difficult to read because of the formatting. Please strip out all the unnecessary blank lines.

Comment: Please reduce the code you are posting to the essential elements that are giving you problems. Then explain exactly what your problem is. This is not a forum for "please do my work for me" questions. You need to show what you tried, how it is not working, and exactly where you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the value to action rather than the previous value and action

```
 tf1.setText(action)
```

Should be

```
 tf1.setText(tf1.getText() + action)
```

Comment: thanks so much, would rep you up but cant as i do not have 15 reputation, this completely fixed my problems. Sorry for not having any proper formatting